# Advance Reporting not working

Tags: reports, user, integration, status, advanced-reporting

I have followed all the instruction to activate advance report
Also Magento Analytics user integration Status is “Active” and generated token But still facing the same error.
We can’t find what you’re looking for.

Comment: Make sure the Cronjob is running. You an see the error on cron_schedule table related to advance reporting.

Comment: cron work properly.

Comment: it will take approx 24 hours to enabled it. You can also see the advance reporting cronjob entry in cron_schedule if its successfully run or not.